# Cron starts a django server, won't complete the command

Tags: python, django, cron

I am having trouble running my Django server in Cron

I am running the following command:

```
* * * * * python $HOME/my/dir/django_bookmarks/manage.py runserver 14.21.141.190:8000 > /another/dir/djsrv.txt
```

cat djsrv returns:

```
Validating models...
```

Anybody know what is wrong?

EDIT:
Command line output looks like this (running normally, not from crontab).

```
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.3, using settings 'django_bookmarks.settings'
Development server is running at http://14.21.141.190:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Comment: It's possible the stdout is line buffered and the redirect is not seeing everything. Is it possible the server is actually up?  Also, I assume from the command line, the command works as expected?

Comment: I checked the server. Doesn't work.
Output from the command line looks like this:
    Validating models...

    0 errors found
    Django version 1.3, using settings 'django_bookmarks.settings'
    Development server is running at http://14.21.141.190:8000/
    Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

Comment: Why are you running the server via cron? I seriously hope you aren't deploying like this.

Comment: Also, you crontab pattern would cause the command to run every minute.

Comment: If it runs from command line and not cron, I'd look at the security context of the cron job. Is it run as root?

Comment: I want to to have it restart every midnight. This is mainly a lightweight tool for internal use. I have also tested an hourly config. The every minute is for testing purposes.

Comment: I usually don't need to. It is certainly being run as the same user. There are no permissions errors coming up -- just truncated + no server.

Comment: Make sure the HOME variable is defined. Also, check the /var/log/syslog for error messages.